# Is it possible to embed React app into AngularJS 1.x?

Tags: reactjs, angularjs

I am building a small React app with the team which uses AngularJS 1.x version.

My approach was to embed `build` folder in one of the AngularJS templates where I expected to see a static generated website `<ng-view id="ng-view-content"></ng-view>` container.

I don't need to share states or components between, I am just looking for a solution for embedding React generated sites into Angular view.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try with an iframe...

Comment: You can `ReactDOM.render()` into any element on the DOM as long as it's there. So figure out where in your Angular app needs to be responsible for that, and have it run that line at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap react components (could be a whole App) in angular components using [react2angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react2angular) and then building react into an npm library that your NG app can import and use. Just as a component library.

this way the react code can be in a different repo

good luck :)